# Minimum weight path

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph with m edges, and let w: E(G)->R be such that w(ei) = 2^i for i = 2,3,...,m. Let T be the min-cost tree of (G,w). For u,v∈V(G), let P(u,v) be a path in G from u to v of minimum weight. Show that P(u,v) ⊆ T.

I am trying to prove by contradiction. Then there exists an edge e in P(u,v) and not in T.
My attempt: may be we can try to remove one edge in Tree T and add e, so there arises contradiction.
However, my confusion is that is it necessary to use the weight function in proof ?

Comment: If you have to prove something about weighted graphs you better take the weight function into account...

Comment: so, we can try to find an edge with smaller weight to replace the edge in T with larger weight ? But it need some construction

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that by “min-cost tree” you are referring to the [*minimum spanning tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), which I will call MST.)

Start off by noting a special property of $w(e_i) = 2^i$, namely that
$$
\sum_{i \in I} 2^i < 2^{k + 1}\tag{*}
$$
for all $I \subseteq \{0, \ldots, k\}$.

Now, you are right with trying to prove this by contraction.

Suppose that the shortest path between $u$ and $v$, $P(u, v)$, is not in the MST.  Let $e$ be the edge on $P(u, v)$ with the largest weight $w$, and let $e'$ be the edge on the unique path between $u$ and $v$ in the MST with the largest weight $w'$.

If $w > w'$, then by $\text{(*)}$ also the weight of the entire path in the MST is less than $w$, contradicting the fact that $e$ is on $P(u, v)$.

If $w < w'$, then by $\text{(*)}$ also the weight of $P(u, v)$ is less than $w'$.  We can therefore remove $e'$ and add $P(u, v)$ to the MST (and then maybe remove some more edges to maintain the tree property) to obtain a spanning tree with smaller weight, contradicting the fact that we had an MST.

---

The bottom line is, your general approach is OK but you need to do some more work.